# Adding Dependency to IntelliJ Project: Take .jar at a Path defined using an Environment variable

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to keep my project free from external data and libraries that will not change during the project (especially since I am going to use git for repo management).

What I want is to be able to add a dependency to the IntelliJ idea project, by referencing it from a system path. This is so that each member of the team does not have to remove and re-add all the jars one by one from his/her local directory containing external libraries.

So when doing: File → Project Structure → Module → Dependencies → Add... → Project Library → Attach Jar, I want to reference the path to the jar file like so:

${EXTERNAL_LIB_DIRECTORY}\libthrift-0.9.2.jar

Essentially, here is a screenshot (made in lowly Paint) illustrating what I am hoping for:

[image]

Is this possible to do in IntelliJ idea?

Comment: Why don't you just use Maven? It works exactly as described, plus you don't need to manage those dependencies yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion myself. I am new to Java and am hence discovering these things afresh. I am guessing maven is to Java projects what CMake is to C++ projects?

Comment: Let try learning and using Maven, it is very good for dependencies managing :) make life easier.